# Strategy Pattern Client implementation problem

Tags: java, strategy-pattern

Currently I'm having a strategy pattern:

```
public interface EncryptionAlgorithm {
    String encrypt(String text);
}

public class Encrypter {
    private EncryptionAlgorithm encryptionAlgorithm;

    String encrypt(String text){
        return encryptionAlgorithm.encrypt(text);
    }

    public void setEncryptionAlgorithm(EncryptionAlgorithm encryptionAlgorithm) {
        this.encryptionAlgorithm = encryptionAlgorithm;
    }
}

public class UnicodeEncryptionAlgorithm implements EncryptionAlgorithm {
    @Override
    public String encrypt(String text) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

I want the Client to be a Cryptographer class which will create the Contexts (I have a decryptor as well, same as encryptor), but I'm struggling with making these method.

```
public class Cryptographer {

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cryptographer cryptographer = new Cryptographer();
        cryptographer.setCryptographer(new Encrypter());
        cryptographer.setAlgorithm(new UnicodeEncryptionAlgorithm());
    }
}
```

I tried to make the Cryptographer an interface and implement the methods by the encryptor but it didn't work out. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello Levente Wolf. Can you give more explanations about what didn't work ? Have you problem to compile, to run ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EncryptionAlgorithm` is your strategy. SO here is the same code as yours.

```
public interface EncryptionAlgorithm {
    String encrypt(String text);
}
```

`UnicodeEncryptionAlgorithm` is the concrete strategy and here is the same code. There can be n number of concrete strategies.

```
public class UnicodeEncryptionAlgorithm implements EncryptionAlgorithm {
    @Override
    public String encrypt(String text) {
        return "";
    }
}
```

As per your requirement, `Cryptographer` should be the context. I made it `CryptographerContext` to be more meaningful. If you want you can change the name.

```
public class CryptographerContext {

    private EncryptionAlgorithm encAlgo;

    public void setEncryptionStrategy(EncryptionAlgorithm encAlgo) {
        this.encAlgo = encAlgo;
    }

    public String getEncryptedContents(String text) {
        return encAlgo.encrypt(text);
    }
}
```

In the above context you have to use abstract strategy.

I provide below the main class for testing. If there are many strategies, you have to set the most appropriate strategy for your requirement using `context.setStrategy(concrete impl class)`.

```
public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CryptographerContext cryptographer = new CryptographerContext();
    cryptographer.setEncryptionStrategy(new UnicodeEncryptionAlgorithm());
    String encText = cryptographer.getEncryptedContents("some text");
    System.out.println("Encrypted text: "+encText);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I want to make another strategy (e.g. decrypter), I just make the strategy like the Encrypter and add it's setter and getter to the Context right?

Comment: For another strategy, you can make like MD4EncryptionStrategy, RSAEncryptionStrategy etc. For Decryption, I would suggest to create another context.

Comment: My main problem was to create a context (Cryptographer) for both Strategies (Encrypter and Decrypter). Because in my original code i have an ecryptor and a decryptor context. So, you say it is better to separate the contexts?

Comment: Yes, as encryption and decryption are different and there should be different interfaces as per this design context.